# C array of void pointers holding different value types

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

I'm trying to have a void array with 3 pointers:

```
char v1='c'; 
int v2 =12;
int const numOfArgs=3;
char v3[3] = "geo";
void *arg1 = &v1;
void *arg2 = &v2;
void *arg3 = &v3;
void *ptrs[numOfArgs]= {arg1,arg2,arg3};
```

I tried in several ways to use one of the pointers from `ptrs`, including casting ,but nothing worked.

How should I approach to it?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly

```
char v3[3] = "geo";
```

does not have enough space to append `'\0'` (C-strings are null-terminated).

So change it to

```
char v3[4] = "geo";
```

---

In order to get the values from `void *ptrs[numOfArgs]`, **type-casting** will work. And don't forget to **dereference** when needed.

Here is an example:

```
printf("\n%c", *(char*)ptrs[0]);
printf("\n%d", *(int*)ptrs[1]);
printf("\n%s", (char**)ptrs[2]);
```

Output:

```
c
12
geo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void *ptrs[numOfArgs]= {arg1,arg2,arg3};
```

When you compile your code, you can get the error:

> variable-sized object may not be initialized

If you want to declare the array on this way, you have to make the constant variable `numOfArgs` by `#define`:

```
#define numOfArgs 3
```

Or you can initialize each element of array of pointer as:

```
    void *ptrs[numOfArgs];
    ptrs[0] = &v1;
    ptrs[1] = &v2;
    ptrs[2] = &v3;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this line:

```
void *ptrs[numOfArgs]= {arg1,arg2,arg3};
```

Is that `ptrs` is a *variable length array*.  Such arrays are not allowed to be initialized because the size it determined at run time.  It doesn't matter that `numOfArgs` is declared as `const`.

You can only initialize an array if its size is a compile time constant, or more formally a **constant expression**.  You can satisify this requirement if the size is a macro.

```
#define numOfArgs 3
```